# Laravel search filter

Tags: php, laravel, search, eloquent

I'm trying to get all columns and values using eloquent style in order to search. This is a Filter function. Seems like I'm doing something wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

```
protected static function search($query, $fields, $value)
{
    return $query->where(function($query) use ($fields, $value){
        collect($fields)->reduce(function($query, $field) use ($value) {
            return $query->OrWhere($field, 'like','%' . $value . '%');
        }, $query);
    });     
}
```

Well when I'm explicitly adding column names it works.

```
return $query->where('title', 'like', '%' .$value. '%')
    ->orWhere('fehlercode', 'like', '%' .$value. '%');
```

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: @mrhn Error 500

Answer (score 0):

I would argue reduce is quite aggressive in this case, this is more for concatenating multiple variables into one, each() is a better method for this. Also the `orWhere()` method is misspelled starting with a capital letter, `Laravel` uses psr2 which uses camel case on the method.

```
return $query->where(function($query) use ($fields, $value){
    collect($fields)->each(function($field) use ($query, $value) {
        $query->orWhere($field, 'like','%' . $value . '%');
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried with `each` as well. I'm still getting an error. Might be the case that the Controller has some bug.

Comment: then post the exact error, you can look in storage/laravel.log